# PySAL natural breaks from Numpy array

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, numpy, pysal, valueerror

I am attempting to extract natural break values from a raster using Python.

The intended process goes: [Arcpy raster object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster/018z00000051000000/) to NumPy Array (using [RasterToNumPyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000)) to natural break values (using [PySAL Natural Breaks function](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/esda/mapclassify.html?highlight=natural%20breaks#pysal.esda.mapclassify.Natural_Breaks)).

```
import arcpy, pysal
from pysal.esda.mapclassify import Natural_Breaks as nb
# code to create greenIndex arcpy Raster object here
greenArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(greenIndex)
breaks = nb(greenArray,k=2,initial=20)
```

This code returns the error, "ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional".

As far as I know, greenArray is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Have you tried checking the greenArray dimensions before trying to process it with Natural_Breaks?  Looks like calling *.shape* on the array will give you the array dimensions.  I haven't done any of this before, but this post seems helpful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061761/numpy-array-dimensions

Comment: Thanks, Branco. I did come across that thread, which lead me to believe that my array was 2-dimensional. The return of greenArray.shape = (1536,2048), and greenArray.ndim = 2. I think I've come up with a solution (using numpy.ravel()), which I will write up shortly.

Comment: @phloem Looking at the PySAL docco I think you're right with using `flatten` and `ravel`; the `Natural_Breaks` appears to only accept a 1d vector of values (or, a `(n, 1)` vector).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the help, Branco and om_henners.

The answer to my problem appears to be to use numpy.ravel() to change the array produced by arcpy.RasterToNumPy() to a 1D array:

```
import arcpy, pysal
from pysal.esda.mapclassify import Natural_Breaks as nb
# code to create greenIndex arcpy Raster object here
greenArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(greenIndex)
breaks = nb(greenArray.ravel(),k=2,initial=20)
```