# Adding natural breaks classification to feature table

Tags: arcgis-pro, features, classification, clustering, natural-breaks

Is there any chance to add the classification classes to the feature table?

I want to divide my feature table (by a numerical field) into x-number of classes. Visually I can see this by classifying the numerical fields for the graduated symbology, however I want to add these classes to the feature table as a new field.

I know I can use a cluster analysis to create the classes, but I would also like to know if there is anyway to add the natural Jenks to the feature table as a new field.

Comment: Have you tried searching this forum? A quick search and you get to this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200618/classifying-data-as-natural-breaks-using-arcpy/394912#394912). Or simply create a new field in your data an assign values using the calculate field tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd, This is how I currently do it, but when using the field calculation tool the entry per category has to be done manually, and if you want to compare different types of classes, and which one behaves better depending on your data set it takes a lot of time. So I was wondering if there was a tool or scrip to do this automatically, since the categories are already created within the graded symbology.

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late to the game for you but... I just discovered the Reclassify Field tool in ArcGIS Pro. I needed to divide my vector data into 5 classes (Natural Breaks) and this tool does it for you!